# preg_match in PHP or similar function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match

I have to use a regular expression to get the text after the last "/" and before "_completed" string.

For example if my input is :

```
http://localhost/project-1/uploaded_images/output//11-03-2013+11-09-2013/Brian_Brown_completed.jpg
```

I need to output "Brian Brown" is that possible with preg_match? Unfortunately I could not figure it out! How about the javascript is it possible there too?

If you need more clarification, please let me know!

EDITED:

Please note that in output I dont have underscore anymore!

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, it's possible in both PHP and Javascript. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I was trying preg_match but I dont know how to pass the pattern!

Comment: The pattern is passed as the first argument.

Comment: But I didnt deserve minus score! :(

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'll bet it was because your question looks like you've made no attempt to solve the problem yourself. There are thousands of questions here with examples of using `preg_match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaScript

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MKC4/)

```
var str = 'http://localhost/project-1/uploaded_images/output//11-03-2013+11-09-2013/Brian_Brown_completed.jpg ';
console.log(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1).split('_completed')[0]);
```

---

Reference

[.lastindexof()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem; I just added split('_')[0] at the very end to get the first part and then split('_')[1] for the second part to get rid of "_" in between Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case a non-regexp solution is acceptable:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/project-1/uploaded_images/output//11-03-2013+11-09-2013/Brian_Brown_completed.jpg';
$test = basename($url, '_completed.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('~([^/]+)_completed\.jpg$~', $url, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
preg_match('#.*/(.*)_completed\.jpg$#', $input, $match); // Find the name
$name = str_replace('_', ' ', $match[1]); // Convert underscores to spaces
```

Javascript:

```
name = /.*\/(.*)_completed\.jpg$/.exec(input)[1].replace(/_/, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$s = str_replace ("_", " ", substr ( $s, strrpos($s, "/")+1, strrpos($s, "_completed")-strrpos($s, "/")-1 )) ;
```